# How to create virtual display, when no screen is connected? (x11vnc)

Tags: xorg, vnc

For an installation I need to have access to the current running screen on a Ubuntu 20 machine.
I want to be able to remotely access it, which I got to work using x11vnc.
But I also want to be able to connect a screen locally, when needed.

Currently if no display is connected the VNC stream is black.
When using `xserver-xorg-video-dummy` it works, but the local screen does not get recognized anymore.
Is there a way to have both running?

I feel like the `-create` option in x11vnc should do what I am looking for, but I can not get it to work.
Here's a snippet from the manual:
-create

> -create
>
> First try to find the user's display using FINDDISPLAY,
> if that doesn't succeed create an X session via the FINDCREATEDISPLAY method. This is an alias for "-display WAIT:cmd=FINDCREATEDISPLAY-Xvfb".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying an HDMI dummy, which fakes a display on hardware level.